# Automatic ETS from fable package in R does not provide the model with the lowest Information Criteria (AIC, BIC and AICc)

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, ets, fable-r

Using the classic shampoo dataset from fpp2 I tried to fit an automatic ets model. This led me to an ETS(A,A,N) framework with aic = 441.0668, bic = 448.9844 and AICc = 443.0668. Nevertheless when using an ETS(A,M,N) model the information criteria metrics are lower (AIC=440.1991, BIC=448.1167, AICc=442.1991), even when the parameter `restrict = FALSE` (on the automatic ets).

```
automatic_fit <- ts_train %>%
  model(ETS(value, restrict= FALSE))

report(automatic_fit)

fit_2 <- ts_train %>%
  model(ETS(value ~ error("A") + trend("M"), restrict = FALSE))

report(fit_2)
```

I know that with the autoarima we have an approximation of the best model since there are to many to check, but I thought that since with ets we have a small number of possibilities we could evaluate all the models. Does anyone knows why we see this results?

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example to get the best answers. I don't know what your `ts_train` dataset is.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the automatic modelling selection done by `fable::ETS` does not consider multiplicative trend models. The models considered in the selection process are described by the `method` argument of the model's specials. The default for the `trend()` special is `trend(method = c("N", "A", "Ad"))`, meaning it will choose the best model between models without trend, with additive trend, and with additive damped trend. To also consider multiplicative trend, you would use `trend(method = c("N", "A", "Ad", "M"))`.